# Is the number of ways to express a number as sum of two coprime squares same as number of solution of $x^2+1\equiv0\pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, sums-of-squares

The number of representations of $n$ by sum of 2 squares is known as sum of square function $r_2 (n)$. It is known that if prime factorization of $n$ is given as
$$2^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}\cdots$$
, where $p_i$s are primes of the form $4k+1$ and $q_i$s are primes of $4k+3$, then $r_2 (n)=0$ if any of $b_i$ is odd and $r_2 (n)=4(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots$ if not.

<del>However, I can't find any result that counts the number of representations of $n$ by sum of 2 **coprime** squares given its factorization. Can you find one?</del>

By simple brute force and searching OEIS, I found that https://oeis.org/A000089 looks nearly identical to the function $r_{2, coprime}(n)$ I explained.

Can you prove or disprove $r_{2, coprime}(n) = A000089(n)$?

Comment: First of all , we have stronger necessary conditions for the existence of such a representation : The number is not divisible by $4$ and there is no prime factor of the form $4k+3$.

Comment: @Peter if we allow equal squares the following would be counter examples for your constraints: $2^2+2^2 = 8$ and $3^2 + 3^2 = 18$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You know, $(2, 2)$ and $(3, 3)$ are not coprimes

Comment: One strategy for trying to count the sums of coprime squares is to  notice that when the squares are not coprime, they have common factors, so they are counted by the $r_2$ of a divisor of $n$.

Comment: @didgogns Of course. I assumed the comment was about your definition of $r_2$ and not about the coprime case, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will just use that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a factorial ring. As before $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\alpha_i}$ where $p_1=2$ and $\alpha_1=0,1$ or $p_i\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ for $i\geq 2$. Then each $p_i$ with $i\geq 2$ factors uniquely as $q_i\overline{q_i}$. Writing $n=a^2+b^2$ corresponds to factoring $n$ as $(a+bi)(a-bi)$ where $(a+bi)$ and $(a-bi)$ are corpime.
Then the statement is clear each factor of $(a+bi)$ is either $q_i^{\alpha_i}$ or $\overline{q_i}^{\alpha_i}$, and if you have $2|n$ you also have a choice for  $(1+i)$ and $(1-i)$. Thus you get exactly $2^k$ such writings.

Comment: P.S the fact that is concides with the number of solutions of the congruence is trivial in one direction; if $n=a^2+b^2$ and $(a,b)$ are coprime then they are coprime with $n$ so $x=a^{-1}b$. The map  backwards relies on Thue's lemma; namely for each such $x$ you can construct $a,b\leq \sqrt{n}$ with $a\equiv xb\pmod{n}$.